# Evaluating complex integral on circle

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to evaluate the integral $$\int \frac{2z-1}{z(z-1)} dz$$ counter clockwise around the circle $$|z|=2$$

First we apply partial fraction decomposition to get $$\int \frac{1}{z}+\int \frac{1}{z-1}$$
And I can write $z=2e^{i\theta}$

So for the first integral $\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{1}{2e^{i\theta}} 2ie^{i\theta} d\theta$ which gives me $2\pi i$

The with the other integral I have $\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{1}{2e^{i\theta}-1}  2ie^{i\theta} d\theta$

Is this on the right lines?

Comment: A partial fraction decomposition of the integrand makes the result clear.

Comment: @danielfischer I have included extra info in my original post, where do I go from there?

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: @danielfischer yes but I am not sure how to apply it!

Comment: If you look at $$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 2} \frac{1}{z-a}\,dz$$ and Cauchy's integral formula, try to relate the parts of one to the parts of the other.

Comment: @danielfischer Looking at the definition of the integral formula, the integral $\int \frac{1}{z-a} dz$ is equal to $2\pi i$ over any circle c centred at a. The first integral was equal to $2\pi i$ so the final answer is as required $4\pi i$.

Comment: The circle need not be centred at $a$, it only needs to have $a$ in its interior.

Comment: @danielfischer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

may be i will learn things carrying out daniel fisher's suggestion in his comments to the op.  let us decompose $$\frac{2z-1}{z(z-1)} = \frac1z+\frac1{z-1}.$$  integrating around these two poles gives you $$\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{2z-1}{z(z-1)} = 4i\pi.$$

$\bf p.s.$  take the circle $|z| = 2,$  going around anti clockwise. deform it by going along just below the positive axis from $z = 2 - i \epsilon,$  go around in a semicircle of radius $\epsilon$ about $z = 1.$  do the same about the point $z = 0.$  the contributions from the two small circles are $2i\pi$ each.

Comment: Why is your integral negative?

Comment: @Braindead, i mad e a sign error. is fixed now.

Comment: @abel would you be so kind as to expand a little on the 'integrating around the pole' bit please?

Comment: @Aljabra, see my edit. i am not an expert on complex. i am trying to learn.